# NHibernate merge associations

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, merge

I'm having issues with merging the following object into another session:

**Entity and it's associations**

Domain -> * Subdomains -> * Controls -> * Measures

The merge on the domain entity works, but it's associations are not merged. How can i fix this?

```
using (var session = SessionFactoryContainer.Current.Get(sessionFactoryName).OpenSession())
            {
                using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        session.Merge(domain);
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Mappings**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using ISMSControl.Domain;

namespace ISMSControl.Infrastructure.Mappings
{
    public class NDomainMapping : ClassMap<NDomain>
    {
        public NDomainMapping()
        {
            Table("domeinen");
            Id(m => m.Id, "id").UnsavedValue(-1);
            Map(m => m.Code, "code_1");
            Map(m => m.Description, "omschrijving");
            Map(m => m.Explanation, "toelichting");
            Map(m => m.DateCreated, "createdat");
            Map(m => m.CreatedBy, "createdby");
            Map(m => m.DateModified, "modifiedat");
            Map(m => m.ModifiedBy, "modifiedby");

            HasMany(m => m.SubDomains)
                .KeyColumn("domein")
                .Inverse()
                .Cascade.All();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own datacontext and mapped the properties to the related columns. My ModelTranslator class translates the domain object to the type object i need for my own datacontext implementation.

I'm still not sure if this is the right solution, but it solved my problem for now.